# Indeterminate Progress Bar Does Not Show when Activity Starts. But Does Other Times

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, progress-bar

I am using `ActionBarSherlock`.  After the Splash screen loads, I start the next `Activity` like so:

```
Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainFragmentActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

In my main `FragmentActivity` I do this:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window;

public class MainFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {


    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);


            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

            // Set up Main Fragment
            FragmentTransaction t2 = this.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            SherlockListFragment mainFrag = new FollowingFragment();
            t2.replace(R.id.main_frag, mainFrag);
            t2.commit();

                   // lots more edited out
    }
```

Over in `FollowingFragment` (which is first `Fragment` to automatically load when `Activity` starts, in my `AsyncTask`, I do this:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
           ((MainFragmentActivity)Context).setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }
```

Here is the problem; when the `Activity` FIRST starts, the ProgressBar does not show.  But once the `Activity` is loaded and the user is swapping out `Fragment`'s, using the same `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);` the Progress Bar spinner shows perfectly.

I am importing all the correct `Sherlock` libraries, using the newest `Sherlock` (4.04 I think?)  Can anyone tell what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

add this line before calling super method in oncreate

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

then add this line before closing the onCreate method instead of onPreExecute

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but does not work.  That first line is already there, by the way.

Comment: so can you pls check onPreExecute method is called or not?

Comment: It is being called.  I have even `Log`'ed a variable out inside.